# Django Iterating over a dictionary which is in a list and showing the data in a template

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

Hello I am a novice programmer

```
def calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b):
    mobiles_list = [mobile_a, mobile_b]

    for mobile in mobiles_list:
        dimension = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(dimension)
        body_material = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(body_material)
        weight = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(weight)

        tech_variables = {'dimension' : dimension, 'body_material' : body_material, 'weight' : weight}

        return render_to_response('compare.html', tech_variables)
```

I have something like this, a list of mobile, assigning values from database and then assigning the variables inside a dictionary. I am thinking of iterating over the dictionary and showing the values in a templates. 
But the problem is I have to make the template to show two mobiles information in one page for comparison. How can I show the two mobiles informations at a time in template? I think the template would always show the information of one mobile. 
Actually I am little bit stuck here, I am not sure what to do now. 
Am I wrong from the beginning? Do I need the dictionary or not? How can I iterate or assign the values for showing in the template. Or am I asking a silly question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Improving Simeon's (supposing a valid `urls.py`),

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def calculateMark(request, mobile_a, mobile_b):
    mobiles_list = [mobile_a, mobile_b]

    results = []
    for mobile in mobiles_list:
        record = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name=mobile).values('dimension', 'body_material', 'weight')
        results += record

    return render(request, 'compare.html', {'data': results})
```

Any notes:

- A view function must have `request` as first parameter.
- filtering always returns list (even only results 1), so `{{ record.dimension }}`, `{{ record.body_material }}`, and `{{ record.weight }}` each will become list. That's why instead of `results.append(dict)`, we use `results += record` so that `{{ record }}` will be rendered appropriately.
- Rendering with `render_to_response` requires `RequestContext`, and Django provides `django.shortcuts.render` to simplify template rendering.

Comment: Hello Aditya, Thanks for your answer This is not my main view function this function called from the main view function so request parameter is missing here.
And I will let you know whether your code works or not. Please suggest me if something on your mind.

Comment: Aditya I have a confusion. I have two mobiles in list. I have to show two mobile specification on one page of template. If I write {{ record.weight }} into my template which mobile's weight it will be?

Comment: Of course, the first is `mobile_a`, then `mobile_b` (because `mobiles_list = [mobile_a, mobile_b]`)

Comment: Hi Aditya, If I do some maths for individual items like record.weight = record.weight/100. After that if I write this line as you said results += record. Would it be ok? Would the "results" variable update by the new values of the items after doing math?

Comment: Or how can I compare two mobiles values inside or outside the for loop? Please don't be annoyed if I am making trouble to you :)

Comment: No problem, Ali. You are only annoying me if you ask for me about `django-annoying` ;-).

Comment: But it's better to explain it in your question about what result looks like you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you intend to do:

```
def calculateMark(mobile_a, mobile_b):
    mobiles_list = [mobile_a, mobile_b]

    results = []
    for mobile in mobiles_list:
        dimension = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(dimension)
        body_material = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(body_material)
        weight = TechSpecificationAdd.objects.filter(mobile_name = mobile).values(weight)

        results.append({'dimension' : dimension, 'body_material' : body_material, 'weight' : weight})

    return render_to_response('compare.html', { 'data': results })
```

In the template you can then do:

```
{% for record in data %}
    {{ record.dimension }}
    {{ record.body_material }}
    {{ record.weight }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hello Simeon thanks for answer, I am trying like your way. if I can get to the solution I would not forget to  accept your answer and vote up you :)

Comment: But why query for the three attributes separately? They're all from the same record. Just get the two model instances and pass them to the template.

Comment: It's not the full code of this function. this function will calculate a mark by fetching the values from database. Thanks for your suggestion.